# Run RMI server Client Remotly on AWS server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rmi

I have open a ec2 ubuntu server on amazon AWS . My problem is that I cant run my RMI project from 2 different machines . More specifically running the client from Windows Netbeans and server from ubuntu server. How is it possible to run them remotely. I have followed a lot of instructions.

I have created a security group on my AWS and accept all inbound connections.
Compiled the rmi locally on server and runs fine . So my guess is that i should oppen rmi port for public ?? I tried but because i work on vm it may not be possible ... Also do I need to bind Netbeans with my ec2 server like Elastic Beanstalk ...

on Server side after 1-2 minutes i get this error

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 34.xxx.xxx.xx; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
```

Server Code :

```
    private static final int port = 1099;
    private static final String hostname = "34.xxx.xxx.xx";
    private static final String bindLocation = "//" + hostname + ":" + port + "/Hello";


public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

    // RMISecurityManager security = new RMISecurityManager();
    // System.setSecurityManager(security);

System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","34.xxx.xxx.xx");
try { // special exception handler for registry creation
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
    System.out.println("java RMI registry created.");
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    // do nothing, error means registry already exists
    System.out.println("java RMI registry already exists.");
}

SkyCorpServer server = new SkyCorpServer();

try {
    Naming.bind(bindLocation, server);

    System.out.println("Addition Server is ready at:" + bindLocation);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Addition Serverfailed: " + e);
}
```

Also i can ping the server from my machine (windows cmd)

THe Client Code :

```
String remoteHostName = "34.xxx.xxx.xx";
        int remotePort = 1099;

        String connectLocation =  "//" + remoteHostName + ":" + remotePort + "/Hello";

        System.out.println("Connecting to client at : " + connectLocation);
        look_op = (ChatInterface)Naming.lookup(connectLocation);
```

Client Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.NotBoundException: Hello
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:209)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
```

I would love any kind of help i have really stack here thanks in advance :D

Comment: So you failed to connect to the Registry when calling `bind()` in the server, and you succeeded in connecting to the Registry in the client but didn't find `"Hello"` there. That suggests that `34.xxx.xxx.xx` isn't the IP address of the server, and that there is already a Registry running there for some other reason.

Comment: Yes I know the weird think is that when i change the servers Ip to localhost runs perfect...

Comment: Of course it does. Why wouldn't it? You need to address the suggestion in my comment.

Comment: So i fixed this ... It turns out that i need to associate the physical ip with the real ip . etc for my occasion i need to run the server like this :
 java SkyCorpServer "172.31.31.94" 666 ... :D Ip and port